# Custom Eclipse warning on an annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

Let's say I have an internal method, which should be used only in certain situations.

Is there any possibility, in Eclipse, to mark it as internal and show a warning when used to prevent me or people who will use my API to use it by mistake not knowing what they're doing. I can't change its visibility as it might be used in other packages/non-extending classes too.

Something like this:

```
@Internal
public void doSomeInternalStuff()
{
    // ...
}
```

And then, a warning in Eclipse:

[image]

You get the point.

Any hope?

Answer (score 10):

[JSR269](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=269) (*Pluggable Annotation Processor API*) allows you to write custom **annotation processors** that can handle custom annotations and enable you to print errors or warning using a `javax.annotation.processing.Messager`.
Below is an example.

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("fully.qualified.name.of.InternalAnnotationType")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class CustomAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(InternalAnnotationType.class)) {
            InternalAnnotationType internalAnnotation = element.getAnnotation(InternalAnnotationType.class);
            String message = "The method " + element.getSimpleName()
                       + " is marked internal and its use is discouraged";
            processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.WARNING, message);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In Eclipse, you can register annotation processors in your Java Compiler by right-clicking on your project, then selecting **Properties** -> **Java Compiler** -> **Annotation Processing** -> **Factory Path** and adding the Jar that contains your custom annotation processor. [Here](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/) is an interesting post that explains the details.

*Alternatively*, you can put all of your "internal" method API inside a dedicated class, and add an ***access rule*** for that class in your Eclipse build path, so that any code in your project that depends on this class would display a warning.

Answer (score -3):

Read about internal methods int Herbert Schildt's book "Java: beginers guide"
here's link:[http://www.amazon.com/Java-Beginners-Guide-5th-Edition/dp/0071606327](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071606327)