# Force warning when class is not closed

Tags: java, eclipse, resource-leak

When I work with IO classes like `java.util.Scanner` or `java.io.BufferedReader`, Eclipse displays a warning `Resource leak: 'suchAndSuch' is never closed`.  How can I make Eclipse display this warning for my own class when it is not closed?

What I want to know is if there is an Interface or something I need to implement to make my class be treated like the IO classes, so that it's independent of any one IDE, e.g. the command line `javac` also displays a warning when a resource isn't closed.

Comment: use Pluggable Annotation Processor API http://stackoverflow.com/a/24981511/3651739

Comment: Have you tried implementing the `java.io.Closeable` interface in the class that you want Eclipse to warn you about?

Comment: Is it sufficient to have your class implement `java.io.Closeable`? See http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-avoiding_resource_leaks.htm .

Comment: @JonK I did once, but for whatever reason it didn't work.  I guess Eclipse doesn't check if the object is closed if it's passed to another method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse gives warning "never closed" for any class which implements java.io.Closeable

```
class X implements Closeable {
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
    }
}

...
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        X x = new X(); <-- Eclipse warning
    }
```