# Java "Resource Leak" Warning Not Triggering When it Should

Tags: java, resource-leak, autocloseable, java-annotations

I have a class called `JavaShellStream` that extends the interfaces `Closeable` and `Autocloseable`. However, when I use the class, and **do not call its `close()` method**, no warning is triggered that there is a resource leak. I have another class called `JavaShell` which has a method called `exec(String cmd)` that returns a `JavaShellStream` object. When I create a new `JavaShellStream` object in the following way, no resource leak warning is triggered:

```
//workingDir is a File object that sets the working directory
JavaShell js = new JavaShell(workingDir); 
//execute the "ls" command and retrieve output as a JavaShellStream
JavaShellStream jss = js.exec("ls");
/*
 * some code to read the text from the stream
 * but DOES NOT close the stream
 */
// Note that I am NOT calling the close() method
```

Why is no warning triggered here that there is a resource leak because the `JavaShellStream jss` is never closed? The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921293/force-warning-when-class-is-not-closed) says that all that's required to trigger it is to implement the interface `Closeable`, but my class implements both `Closeable` and `Autocloseable` but will not trigger any warning when unclosed.

Comment: I have the same issue. The issue is caused when a resource instance is returned by a method instead of newly created. Unfortunately there is no solution for that (yet).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse (as the linked question relates to), there is an option to display a warning where there is a possibility of a resource leak.

Go to *Window* > *Preferences* > *Java* > *Compiler* > *Errors/Warnings*, and set the severity level of "Potential resource leak" to *Warning*.