# How to raise a warning if the close() function of a user-defined class isn't called?

Tags: java

I've been searching how to raise a warning in Java if a specific object from a class that has a **close()** function in it doesn't at some point call that **close()** function (as for example for the *BufferedReader* class).

In searching through this, I found the *Closeable* and *AutoCloseable* interfaces and how they work, as well as this questionn that helped a lot : [Force warning when class is not closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921293/force-warning-when-class-is-not-closed/66874541#66874541)

But I still face the issue that when the object in question is created through a function, it is not supposed that it hasn't been closed.

For instance, in this code :

```
//X.java
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;

public class X implements Closeable{

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("CLOSE");
    }
}
```

```
//Main.java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    X x = new X();
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

A ressource leak warning is raised, but in this one (same X.java) :

```
//Main.java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = getX();
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static X getX(){
        return new X();
    }
}
```

No warning is raised where I want one to be.

Thanks !

Comment: Finalizers? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer

Comment: Isn't the finalizer the function that is runs when the GC deallocates the ressources (that is to say, whenever it wants to/can) ? Because it was my first option but since I have to close big chunks of data (hundreds of Mbs to Gbs worth) this led to a LOT of memory being used up, which isn't an option... I need the close() function I think, since there is no way to force Object finalization.