# How is Java annotation processor implemented?

Tags: java, annotations

I am writing some app in which I use integer to represent different types of semantics.  For example, I use int to represent both month and year, and I want to avoid accidentally using variables with one semantic in the context requiring the other.  I want to use annotation to annotate variables representing month with `@Month` and ones representing year with `@Year`, and would like compiler to warn me if unexpected assignment or method call.  How do I implement that?

BTW: I don't want to introduce additional classes Month and Year because it is not as efficient and kind of verbose in syntax, e.g. I need to call `month.get()` to use it where an int is expected, and `new Month(m)` to create.

I tried to search online but don't find enough document.  Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, this requires *type annotations* (which were introduced in Java 8). For this type of application, you will want to have a look at the Checker Framework. Here's a good starting point: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html

Comment: @aioobe thanks, looks promising, I didn't know its existence. Let me check it out.

Comment: Do you want to implement your own [annotation preprocessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979971/custom-eclipse-warning-on-an-annotation) to look for those?